# Accessing the google calendar using a refresh token

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

Is this the right way to access the google calendar api using a refresh token? That's 2 weeks after a user gave me his consent.

```
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
    process.env.DOMAIN_NAME + "/google/oauth/callback"
);


 oauth2Client.setCredentials({
        refresh_token: refreshToken
    })
    const calendar = google.calendar({version: "v3", auth: oauth2Client});
    calendar.events.watch({
        auth: oauth2Client,
        resource: {
            id: makeid(10) + Date.now(),
            token: process.env.GOOGLE_API_WATCH_TOKEN,
            type: 'web_hook',
            address: "https://" + process.env.DOMAIN_NAME + "/google/notifications"
        },
        calendarId: "primary"
    }, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            defer.reject(error);
        } else {
            defer.resolve(response);
        }
    });
    return defer.promise;
```

I'm not using jwt.

Comment: Hi there @ChrisHansen! I can't understand your question, could you please clarify where you need help? Does the script return any errors?

Comment: refresh token is a jwt you are using jwt.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron Is this the right way to use the google calendar api with a refresh token?

Comment: Hey Chris, how're you handling the refresh_token?  when you provide the refresh_token via setCredentials, the googleapis library will handle the process of asking for a new access token if the current one is about to expire (A refresh token allows your application to obtain new access tokens), so for your question, seems you're using it properly, I don't know the details about how you're dealing with the refresh token. Save refresh tokens in secure long-term storage and continue to use them as long as they remain valid. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows a valid approach to token handling if it doesn't generate any issues. As an answer, I show below an alternative to OAuth 2.0 token handling.

This code will first read the token file with the [`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlereadfileoptions) method. Then it will be fed to the `authorize` function. That function will set up the objects used on the authentication flow, and if it fails (due to an invalid token, per example) then it will call the `getAccessToken` function to gather new tokens.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {
  google
} = require('googleapis');

const SCOPES = ['{YOUR SCOPES HERE}'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';


fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listEvents);
});


function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {
    client_secret,
    client_id,
    redirect_uris
  } = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);


  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}


function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });

  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });

  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token',
        err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}
```

Please write back if you have doubts about this approach or your own.